# Understanding operators using sed

Tags: shell, sed

Trying to understand and break down this command.

```
echo -e '1234\n4567' | sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)$/\1:\2/'
```

Comment: Just trying to get a better understanding of the various operators to better use the tools

Comment: In reading various pieces online it appears 's/^ searches from the beginning '1234\4567' the \ is an escape? not sure what (..\) means (move two decimal places? escape
what does the $/\1:\2/' mean?

Comment: Found a great site test and break it down.

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Apologize, Sukminder had it correct, I made a typo. The desired output was
12:34 
45:67
Not sure why people would minus one for someone trying to learn considering I stated "novice". What I learned was also were to find the details in the man pages across the two commands based on the detailed response. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo -e '1234\n4567'
```

- `echo`
  Write arguments to the standard output.
- `-e`
  Enable interpretation backslash escapes.
- `'1234\n4567'`
  The sequence to be written. Here quoted in single quotes. The `\n` is a *backslash escape* that produces a new-line. Without the `-e` option to `echo` this would have produced a literal `\n`. See `man echo`.

---

```
|
```

- `|`
  Pipe *standard output* from the left, `echo`, to the *standard input* for command on the right, `sed`.

---

```
sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)$/\1:\2/'
```

- `sed`
  s(tream) ed(itor)
- `'s/^\(..\)\(..\)$/\1:\2/'` → `s/ A / B /`
  `s`ubstitute A with B
- A: `^\(..\)\(..\)$`

  - `^` Start of line

    - `\(` Start capture group 1. `(` would have been a literal `(`.

      - `.` Match any character and add it to capture group 1.
      - `.` Match any character and add it to capture group 1.
    - `\)` End capture group 1.
    - `\(` Start capture group 2.

      - `.` Match any character and add it to capture group 2.
      - `.` Match any character and add it to capture group 2.
    - `\)` End capture group 2.
  - `$` Match end of line.
- B: `\1:\2`

  - `\1` Print capture group 1.
  - `:` Print a literal `:`
  - `\2` Print capture group 2.

---

In other words:

Write:

```
1234
4567
```

to standard out and pipe it to `sed`.

In `sed`; read from standard input and match lines of four characters. Separate the first two from the two last with a colon and print the result:

```
12:34
45:67
```

Comment: I believe that I understood most of that -  turn 1234<newline>4567 into a properly formatted time. One thing though, I haven't grasped where the <space> and the . <full stop> are coming from? I get the colon.

Comment: @Vérace: What space/full stop? Added *«result»*.

Comment: The OP's desired output is 12:34 45.67 i.e. a time?

Comment: @Vérace: Ah. Thought you were OP at first. Anyhow: the way I interpret it is that OP want to know what `echo -e '1234\n4567' | sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)$/\1:\2/'` does. He want to have it broken down. I notice now he has a dot in comment saying *"the output is 12:34 45.67"* – but can not see how that is other then a typo on his part. – That would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @Vérace: `'{N;s/\(..\)\(..\)\n\(..\)\(..\)/\1:\2 \3.\4/}'` , but do not see how that is part of OP's question.

Comment: Very nice - if I could give this a +1 I would!